# Where did the question edits go?

Tags: support, specific-question, editing

I am sure I edited [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37233/software-to-wake-up-the-pc-at-a-specific-time-in-future-just-like-alarm-do-for) earlier today.

I asked the OP for clarification (Do you mean 'hibernation'?) and edited his response into the title, among other things.

But I see no rollbacks, no denied flags, no edit or comment history (nothing in my *All actions* list), no search hits on 'hibernation', no duplicate questions from the author, nada....
I checked the same clues at Productivity.SE because these kinds of questions are asked there too (and the user has no questions there).

So, out of curiosity: **What (can have) happened?**

Maybe if a user deletes his question and writes it again there are no traces left to see for others (below 10k)?
Or a rollback of some kind happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit suggestion was rejected:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24393

(You can find these under: [Activity: all actions: suggestions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/416/jan-doggen?tab=activity&sort=suggestions))

Comment: Weird. Well OK, thanks.